# Does an Accesrail intermodal ticket guarantee connections to and from flights?

Tags: air-travel, uk, trains, intermodal

The [Accesrail website](http://www.accesrail.com/sc/first-great-western.html) states:

> First Great Western now provides, thanks to AccesRail, its first air-rail intermodal solution. This allows passengers to go to/from Heathrow or Gatwick Airport to their First Great Western destination of choice.
>
> Passengers receive an intermodal ticket that covers both their flight and rail journey. Depending on which airport the passenger travels, train connections are slightly different.

If I have an intermodal ticket, does that mean I am guaranteed a connection from the train to the flight and vice versa?  I mean in case of delays.  At one point the Swedish railways SJ and the Swedish airline SAS had such an agreement (perhaps they still do) when connecting from the train to a SAS flight within Europe.

Comment: It's only valid on a handful of airlines, list at the bottom of the page you linked to. Based on articles in the travel press I read when it launched with Singapore Airlines (the first), I think it does mean that a delayed train would lead to a free re-booking of your flight. Maybe google for that to find details on one of the other GWR sites? (It's no longer FGW, as of 2 weeks ago it's now GWR...)

Answer (score 4):

Searching on [Matrix](http://matrix.itasoftware.com/), it is possible to find a fare from, for example, OXF (Oxford railway station) to MUC (Munich). An example fare is
Carrier 9B ZNXADT OXF to LON, where 9B is the IATA code for AccesRail (in this case a National Express Coach journey) connecting to fare Carrier KL T7WKWGB LON to MUC, where KL is KLM.

The fare rules for the 9B fare contain:

> Fare rules & restrictions AccesRail and Partner Railways (9B) ZNXADT
>   OXF to LON   NATIONAL EXPRESS ONE WAY FARES
>   APPLICATION
>    AREA
>        THESE FARES APPLY
>        FROM UNITED KINGDOM TO LON.
>   CLASS OF SERVICE
>        THESE FARES APPLY FOR ECONOMY CLASS SERVICE.
>   TYPES OF TRANSPORTATION
>        THIS RULE GOVERNS ONE-WAY FARES.
>        FARES GOVERNED BY THIS RULE CAN BE USED TO CREATE
>        ONE-WAY JOURNEYS.      RAILWAY CONDITION APPLY.

If this is booked as one ticket, normal protection rules will apply and a missed connection would result in flight/bus/rail rebooking for following segments.

[image]

Comment: That Oxford to LHR leg wouldn't actually be National Express though. They might sell you the ticket, but pretty sure it'd actually be the [Oxford Bus company Airline bus](http://airline.oxfordbus.co.uk/heathrow/) for which NEX sell some tickets

Comment: Indeed: Service OXLHR

This is not a National Express coach; it is operated by Oxford Bus Company.